# How to understand a 32 bar progression

Tags: theory, musical-forms

I am learning some country progressions. There is a waltz time 32 bar progression in the style of some old Tex Ritter song, I think. It's not just two 16 bar progressions (the last two 16 bars are different from the first).

My two questions are:

1. Is there anything as a standard 32 bar progression?
2. In blues you often use standard progressions and jam around the chords. Does it work the same with this kind of music?

Comment: I feel like jamming around the chords is a possibility for any kind of music, assuming you either know the chords or have a chord chart in front of you.

Comment: There are a few common 32-bar progressions: AABA and ABAC are two.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very common form for modern music and it can be seen in one of the most iconic standards *I Got Rhythm* and other rhythm changes songs. The changes for that song are depicted below.

[image]

The basic form breaks down to an AA'BA where each letter is an 8 bar phrase. The A sections are obviously the same. A' is mostly A, but with a slightly different ending to get you to the B section which is very different from the A section. If you are interested in the specific analysis of this piece, [Wiki as a very nice article about it in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythm_changes#Application).

Improvisation and jamming is the same as any other form and in general, unless the form you pick is too hard to "feel" you should have no problem jamming on it. There are plenty of changes to play over and you can trade fours although trading eights would better fit this specific form.